# delay() and fadeOut() don't delay attr() in the queue

Tags: jquery, delay, attr

what is wrong in this code? I'm trying to get this effect: `fadeOut(500)` and `attr('class','myClass')` delayed by 600 millisecs.. then `delay(600)` again, and `fadeIn(500)`. The delays happen correctly but the `attr()` is not being delayed, it fires when `#myDiv` is still fading! :'(

```
$('#myDiv').fadeOut(500)
           .delay(600)
           .attr('class','myClass')
           .delay(600)
           .fadeIn(500);
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) only affects the animation or `fx` queue (unless you specify a different queue specifically).  Keep in mind that chaining and queuing are 2 distinctly different concepts, chaining continues the use of the same jquery set, but that's a different thing entirely than any event queues on elements in that set.

To have the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) call affected, you have to add it as a callback to that same queue using [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/), like this:

```
$('#myDiv').fadeOut(500)
           .delay(600)
           .queue(function(next) { $(this).attr('class','myClass'); next(); })
           .delay(600)
           .fadeIn(500);
```

Also note there are [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) and [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) methods available that may make this a bit cleaner :)

Comment: I think you should call `$(this).dequeue()` inside the function. From the docs: *Note that when adding a function with .queue(), we should ensure that .dequeue() is eventually called so that the next function in line executes.* Anyway +1 ;)

Comment: @Felix - Woops I'm usually calling this as the last item in the queue, good catch :)

Comment: Hi Nick,

thanks a lot for your answer. It works as you say, however the following calls in queue don't work anymore.. :(

EDIT saw only now Felix comment.. thanks a lot to both of you guys

Comment: @luca - Make sure you're trying the latest answer...that's the thing Felix pointed out in comments, it should work now  :)

Comment: thank you for posting this question it help me fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

Our problem with this code is that You didn't use queue function with is neceserly when You try execute my different jquery effects.

For example we can make this :

```
$('some_element').faddeToggle(1000).delay(3000).css('some_style','value');
```

but if You have more it should be in some order.

My propositions is :

```
$('#myDiv').fadeIn(4000)
        .delay(2000);
        console.log($($('#myDiv')).attr('id'));
        $('#myDiv').attr('class','myClass')  
 $('#myDiv').fadeOut(2000)
            .delay(3000).queue(function(){
            $('#myDiv').attr('class','newClass');
            var status = $('#myDiv').attr("class"); 
            console.log(status);
          });
```

Here You have additionally how class is changed. I hope it will help You