# .delay() function doesn't work on attr() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some images in my website and with this code I would like to hide them, change the shown image and show them back, but the new picture shows instantly. I don't know what to do.

This is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.show').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("show").addClass("clickedShow");
    $('.show').animate({opacity: 0}, 1000);
    $(this).delay(1000).animate({opacity: 0}, 1000);

    $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 1000).attr("src", "pic2.png");
    $('.show').delay(1000).animate({opacity: 1}, 1000).attr("src", "pic2.png");
  });
});
```

Comment: this will solve your problem:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807127/jquery-delay-doesnt-delay-attr-in-the-queue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`delay` works only for animations that can be queued, `attr` is not queued hence it's not affected by the `delay`. If you want to do something at the end of the animation add the action to the `animation` callback.

```
$(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 1000, function(){$(this).attr("src", "pic2.png")});
```

Answer (score 0):

The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay.

So, you can try and use queued jQuery effects and use .delay(1000) in between them. like:

```
$("button").click(function() {
      $("div.first").slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400);
      $("div.second").slideUp(300).fadeIn(400);
    });</script>
```